# How can i convert Object keys to an array of elements that are number of times the key value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, data-structures

**e.g**

```
obj = {a:2, b:3, c:1}
```

The transformed array is:

```
['a','a','b','b','b','c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const obj = {a:2, b:3, c:1};

const res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, key) => {
  return arr.concat( new Array(obj[key]).fill(key) );
}, []);

console.log(res); // ["a","a","b","b","b","c"]
```

**Explanation:**

- `Object.keys()` returns an array of all the keys: `["a", "b", "c"]`
- We then loop over them with `reduce`, and while doing so, we build an array. For every key, we create a new array with the same length as the value, and fill it with the key (`a`, `b`...).
- We then concatenate them together with `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Get entries and take a flat map with an array of a wanted length and fill the array with the key.

```js
const
    object = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 1 },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([key, value]) => Array(value).fill(key));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
let obj = { a:2, b:3, c:1 }
let newObj = [];

for (var key in obj) {
  while (obj[key]) {
    newObj.push(key);
    obj[key]--;
  }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)